# Not sure how to parse this

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
<div class="meaning"><span class="hinshi">［副］</span>物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。</div>
```

All I need from this is `おもに。もっぱら。物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる`.

Usually the hinshi class is separate from the sentences I'm trying to parse, but for some of them they seem to be combined together. Is there anyway to just print the sentence while ignore the `［副］`?

Comment: Where did the first few characters come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get to the desired text.

I'd find a text node in the `div` with `class="meaning"` with `recursive=False`:

```
soup.find('div', class_="meaning").find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Or, you can get the inner `span` element and find the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
soup.find('div', class_="meaning").find('span', class_="hinshi").next_sibling
```

Or with a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div.meaning > span.hinshi')[0].next_sibling
```

Or, you can get the last element from the [`contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) list:

```
soup.select('div.meaning')[0].contents[-1]
```

All four options result into:

```
物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。
```

Comment: Note, this answer is using BeautifulSoup

Comment: @JosepValls sure, exactly what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a couple of ways, namely:

1. Using XPath (through [lxml](http://lxml.de/))
2. Using regular expressions (through the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html))
3. Using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

alcxe and che covered how to do it with method #3, so here are two more ways how to do it:

1. XPath:

   ```
   from lxml.html import fromstring
   s = u'<div class="meaning"><span class="hinshi">［副］</span>物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。</div>'
   print(fromstring(s).xpath('//div/text()')[0])
   ```
2. Regular expressions:

   ```
   import re
   s = u'<div class="meaning"><span class="hinshi">［副］</span>物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。</div>'
   print(re.findall("</span>(.*)</div>", s)[0])
   ```

Both of the above methods require that you learn some new libraries/"sublanguages" (XPath/Regex), but are universal and can be used in many other languages (Beautiful Soup is Python-only).

Happy parsing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit all subtags and just can string contents of `div.meaning`, you can filter the nodes by looking at its `name` attribute (which only tags have):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
s = BeautifulSoup('[<div class="meaning"><span class="hinshi">［副］</span>物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。</div>]')
nodes = s.find('div', 'meaning').contents
only_strings = [x for x in nodes if getattr(x, 'name', None) is None]                                           
print ''.join(only_strings)
```

will get you

```
物事の重点・大勢を述べるときに用いる。
```

(presuming "おもに。もっぱら。" was a typo as it's nowhere in the source string)